# I want execute a condition to ignore specific pdf from xml list via xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

```
<content template="document-gallery">
      <document lanuage="en" ref="http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Memphis/808638903en.pdf" title="Complete Owner's Guide"/>
      <document lanuage="fr" ref="http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Memphis/808638903fr.pdf" title="Complete Owner's Guide"/>
      <document lanuage="en" ref="http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Memphis/809008405.pdf" title="Wiring Diagram"/>
      <document lanuage="en, es, fr" ref="http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Memphis/809018701.pdf" title="Installation Instructions"/>
      <document lanuage="en" ref="http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Specsheets/E30DF74TP_0418_EN.pdf" title="Product Specifications Sheet"/>
    </content>
```

As per above xml if lanuage='fr' and lanuage='es' ignore this PDF and if pdf ends with 'es.pdf' and 'fr.pdf' also ignore it. But, if lanuage='en,es,fr' do not ignore this PDF

Here what I have written:

```
<xsl:template match="document">
            <xsl:if test="not(matches(@lanuage,'sp') or ends-with(@ref,'sp.pdf') or matches(@lanuage,'fr') or ends-with(@ref,'fr.pdf')) or matches(@lanuage,'en')">
                <xsl:variable name="href" select="js:call($resource-to-collect,string(@ref))"/>
                <a type="{name()}" href="{$href}"><xsl:apply-templates select="@* except(@ref)"/><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></a>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Please tag or mention your XSLT version: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 which can be shown with fuller XSLT and not one template snippet. Also, please describe what is wrong with posted XSLT. Any errors or undesired results?

Comment: its version 2.0

Comment: And issue with code? And is *lanuage* misspelled for *language*? And why is *sp* in your `test` logic as you do not mention this criteria in post?

Comment: Hi, Parfait "lanuage" is coming from the XML file and it is from client side only.

Comment: Please answer my repeated question: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: My code excluded ("<document lanuage="en, es, fr" ref="http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Memphis/809018701.pdf" title="Installation Instructions"/>") this PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Consider combining string matches with pipes, `|`, and run a conditional template match rather than `<xsl:if>`. Due to overlap of *fr* and *es* in *en, es, fr*, add an `or` condition on exact string match:

```
  <xsl:template match="document[not(matches(@lanuage, 'fr|es') or
                                    ends-with(@ref, 'fr.pdf|es.pdf'))
                                or @lanuage = 'en, es, fr']]">
      <xsl:variable name="href" select="js:call($resource-to-collect,string(@ref))"/>
      <a type="{name()}" href="{$href}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except(@ref)"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </a>
  </xsl:template>
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYir/1) *(removes unknown `js:call` call)*